# Using jsonb_set inside of jsonb_set to update different values in one query(PostgreSQL)

Tags: json, postgresql

What I'm trying to do is using jsonb_set statement as argument of other jsob_set, but it looks like it is not working as I expected.

```
config_data = jsonb_set(
                 (jsonb_set(
                    config_data::jsonb,
                    '{s}',
                    config_data::jsonb->'s' || '{"ssss":1234}'::jsonb
                 ))::jsonb,
                 '{s}',
                 config_data::jsonb->'s' || '{"sss":3}'::jsonb
              ),
```

This is a structure of a query, but it returns

```
config_data = {"s":{"ss":22,"sss":3,"ssss":4}}
```

As we see, "ssss" value was not affected. Any suggestions on this one?

Comment: What would you expect instead?

Comment: `config_data = {"s":{"ss":22,"sss":3,"ssss":1234}} `
Noticed one exta "s" in second statement ( updated )

Comment: Ok. And what was the value before the operation?